# ValueError: Grouper for 'xxxx' not 1-dimensional

Tags: python, pandas

For the following code input

```
cyclestrain = train.groupby('Unit', as_index=True)['cycles'].max()
cyclestest = test.groupby('Unit', as_index=True)['cycles'].max()
```

I am getting this error:

> File
>   "D:/FH-Sudwestfalen/CMAPSS_Aircraft_Data/predict-remaining-useful-life-master/neuralnetwork.py", line 57, in 
>       cyclestrain = train.groupby('Unit', as_index=True)['cycles'].max()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\nvidh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
>   line 6665, in groupby
>       observed=observed, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\nvidh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py",
>   line 2152, in groupby
>       return klass(obj, by, **kwds) File "C:\Users\nvidh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py",
>   line 599, in **init**
>       mutated=self.mutated)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\nvidh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py",
>   line 3315, in _get_grouper
>       if not isinstance(gpr, Grouping) else gpr
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\nvidh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py",
>   line 3025, in **init**
>       raise ValueError("Grouper for '%s' not 1-dimensional" % t)
>
> ValueError: Grouper for 'Unit' not 1-dimensional

Comment: What is `print (train.columns)` and `print (test.columns)` ? It seems duplicated column `Unit`